# Angularjs sets display none when iterate model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am confused about this problem. I am trying to develop a little custom slider. The slider has two parts(left and right slider). left slider is a social platform slider and the other slides their posts. For example when facebook selected in left slider, right slider must show facebook posts.That is what i am trying to do.

The problem all list item's display property in the right slider are none.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alikoyuncu/4z8ou2so/1/)

HTML:

```
<div style="width:60%;display:block;float:left;height:100%;">
            <ul class="slider_mecra_data">
                <li class="list_item" index="{{$index}}"  ng-style="$index > 2 && {'display':'none'} || {'display': 'block'}"  is_first="{{ $index == 0 ? true : false}}" ng-repeat="data in mecra_datas track by $index">
                    <div class="to_right_gradient" style="display:block;position:relative;color:white;">
                        <div style="display:block">
                            <div style="display:block">
                                <div style="display:inline-block;width:10%">
                                    <div style="position:relative;">
                                        <div class="image-cropper profile_img_over_mecra">
                                            <img ng-src="{{data.profile_pic}}" class="profile_img" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="image-cropper" style="position:relative;">
                                            <img ng-src="{{data.post_pic}}" class="post_image" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block;width:60%;">
                                    <div class="post_content">
                                        <div style="display:block;">
                                            {{data.screen_name}}
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="display:block;">
                                            @{{data.user_name}}
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="display:block;">
                                            {{data.spot}}
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="display:block;margin-top:10px;">
                                            <span>{{data.index_tarih}}</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block;width:10%;">
                                    <div>
                                        <div style="font-size:4vw">
                                            <span>{{data.follower_count/1000 | number:1}}</span><span style="font-size:1.5vw">k</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="display:block; font-size:1.5vw">
                                            Takipci Sayisi
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="display:inline-block; border-left: 1px solid #9EADCC;width:10%;">
                                    <div style="padding-left:10px;">
                                        <div style="font-size:4vw">
                                            <span>{{data.erisim_count/1000 | number:1}}</span><span style="font-size:1.5vw">k</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="display:block; font-size:1.5vw">
                                            Erisim Sayisi
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("waroom", []);
 app.controller('ControllerSecondPage', function ($scope, $rootScope, $interval, $timeout) {
            $scope.active_mecra_sid = 1;
            $scope.mecra_datas = [];
            $scope.slider_interval = null;
            $scope.mecras = [
                {
                    "name": "facebook", "sid": 1, "data_count": 1.1, 'datas': [
                    { "sid": 1, "user_name": "niseifimo_1_1", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 1, "user_name": "niseifimo_1_2", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 1, "user_name": "niseifimo_1_3", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 1, "user_name": "niseifimo_1_4", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 1, "user_name": "niseifimo_1_5", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                ]},
                {
                    "name": "twitter", "sid": 2, "data_count": 1.1, 'datas': [
                    { "sid": 2, "user_name": "niseifimo_2_1", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 2, "user_name": "niseifimo_2_2", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 2, "user_name": "niseifimo_2_3", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                ] },
                {
                    "name": "instagram", "sid": 3, "data_count": 1.1, "datas": [
                    { "sid": 3, "user_name": "niseifimo_3_1", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 3, "user_name": "niseifimo_3_2", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 3, "user_name": "niseifimo_3_3", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                ]},
                {
                    "name": "youtube", "sid": 4, "data_count": 1.1, "datas": [
                    { "sid": 4, "user_name": "niseifimo_4_1", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 4, "user_name": "niseifimo_4_2", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 },
                    { "sid": 4, "user_name": "niseifimo_4_3", "screen_name": "nise rakac", "profile_pic": "images/nagi.png", "post_pic": "images/nagi.png", "spot": "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC", "index_tarih": new Date(), "follower_count": 1500, "erisim_count": 3211 }
                ] }
            ];
            $scope.getMecraDatas = function(){
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mecras.length; i++) {
                    var mecra = $scope.mecras[i];
                    if(mecra.sid == $scope.active_mecra_sid)
                        return mecra.datas;
                }
                return [];
            }
            $scope.mecra_data_slider = function () {
                var slider_list_items = [];
                var slider = $('.slider_mecra_data');
                $(slider).find('li').each(function () {
                    slider_list_items.push(this);
                });
                if (slider_list_items.length < 4)
                {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        $scope.mecra_slider();
                    }, 5000);
                } else {
                    var first_list_item = slider_list_items[0];
                    var top_item = slider_list_items[1];
                    var middle_item = slider_list_items[2];
                    var bottom_item = slider_list_items[3];
                    $(first_list_item).slideToggle(function () {
                        $(first_list_item).remove();
                        slider.append(first_list_item);
                    });
                    var is_first = $(bottom_item).attr("is_first");
                    if (is_first == "true") {
                        $scope.mecra_slider();
                    } else {
                        $(bottom_item).slideDown('show');
                    }
                }
            };
            $scope.mecra_slider = function () {
                var slider_list_items = [];
                var slider = $('.slider_mecra');
                $(slider).find('li').each(function () {
                    slider_list_items.push(this);
                });
                var first_list_item = slider_list_items[0];
                var top_item = slider_list_items[1];
                var middle_item = slider_list_items[2];
                var bottom_item = slider_list_items[3];
                $(first_list_item).slideToggle(function () {
                    $(first_list_item).remove();
                    slider.append(first_list_item);
                });
                $(bottom_item).slideDown('show');
                $(top_item).removeClass('active_list_item');
                $(middle_item).addClass('active_list_item');
                $scope.active_mecra_sid = parseInt($(middle_item).attr("sid"));
                $scope.mecra_datas = $scope.getMecraDatas();
                $interval.cancel($scope.slider_interval);
                $scope.start_slider();

            };
            $scope.start_slider = function () {
                $scope.slider_interval = $interval(function () {
                    $scope.mecra_data_slider();
                }, 2000);
            }
            $scope.start = function () {
                $scope.mecra_datas = $scope.getMecraDatas();
                $scope.start_slider();
            };
            $scope.start();
        });
```

As you see on jsfiddle, when pass to next element in left slider, all list items's display property in the riht slider are none. I couldn't solve this problem and need your help.

Comment: So, on your ng-style directive (top of html) ... Is that supposed to say "hide if $index > 2 and add is_first class if $index==0)?

Comment: yes, removing that condition does not solve the problem. I tried to remove that condition and it did not solve.

Comment: OK ... one last question ... what is the core of that switch.  you have a few timers going, but I cant pinpoint where in the code you switch the elements from one feed to the next.  where is that??

Comment: actually the middle item in the left slide is the right slide's switcher. So when twitter turn up to facebook, right slide shows facebook posts. in the mecra_data_slider method i call mecra_slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was javascript slideToggle. It has a timer mechanism, so it hides element and angular compiler can't handle this elements. So I've changed a little bit code line ant it works.

```
$scope.mecra_data_slider = function () {
    console.log('mecra_data_slider');
    var slider_list_items = [];
    var slider = $('.slider_mecra_data');
    $(slider).find('li').each(function () {
        slider_list_items.push(this);
    });
    if (slider_list_items.length < 4)
    {
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.mecra_slider();
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        var first_list_item = slider_list_items[0];
        var top_item = slider_list_items[1];
        var middle_item = slider_list_items[2];
        var bottom_item = slider_list_items[3];
        var is_first = $(bottom_item).attr("is_first");
        //when i slide right slider, it won't call slideToggle.
        if (is_first == "true") {
            $scope.mecra_slider();
        } else {
            $(first_list_item).slideToggle(function () {
                $(first_list_item).remove();
                slider.append(first_list_item);

            });
            $(bottom_item).slideDown('show');
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

OK.... That was fun.  I think I may have figured it out [in this fork of your jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fknwqwz2/).

You use `.slideDown()` The problem is: **.SlideDown is setting the display:none property for your li elements, but you never UNDO that when you switch to a new feed.**  Just add a line to clear out the display:none that your .slideDown() calls have added and you should be all set:

```
...
$scope.mecra_data_slider = function () {
   var slider_list_items = [];
   var slider = $('.slider_mecra_data');
   $('.slider_mecra_data .list_item').css('display','block');
   .....
```

Comment: when i check your fork, it seems that it doesn't solve the problem. Can you test your fork.

Comment: Check your timers too. They're stepping on eachother I think.

Comment: yes, and when you add that line to place where you showed, the slider shows all list items too.

Comment: i solve it @bri, the problem was slideToggle. Slidetoggle has timer that is why angular can't handle the last item in the list. I will accept your answer, because i can't selve this problem without your answer!

Comment: Cool!  Thanks for the note. I was mentally rewriting your code while driving (which can't be good).  Glad you solved it.